# Is there a shortcut for setting !important on every property in a CSS file?

Tags: css

I have a large CSS file for which I would like to add `!important` to every CSS property. Is there one-line shortcut to make a whole .css file `!important`?

Comment: Is this really the underlying problem? I have a suspicion that you may have fallen victim to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I'm wrong, please correct me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to override styles by importing another stylesheet, you should use the order of precedence.

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="style-override.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Here the `style.css` is the original and `style-override.css` would contain your new custom css. These styles will override the styles from `style.css`. This means you won't need to use `!important` because the style is overwritten.

Alternatively you could add in a CSS reset to remove all styles and build on-top of that.

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="style-override.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Check out a CSS reset at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and add it to reset.css.

Answer (score 4):

No. Also, don't overuse `!important`: it should be a last resort. The effect of applying `!important` to all CSS declarations is equivalent to having no `!important` added to each declaration.

Use more specific selectors (`#id`) instead of adding `!important` if you want a certain property to take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

No. Using !important should only be in specific no-other-way cases. It is not intended to be applied to a whole stylesheet document.

If you are thinking about overwriting so many rules why not just not include the rules you want to overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to move the CSS file link to be the last one being referenced and hence takes precedence over all other CSS files above it?